# What is a easy way to sign a Apt package

Tags: apt, signature

I built my own linux shell and I built the package I can install it with `apt install sturtzshell` and it runs like it is supost to when you type `sturtz` But When I run edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` I had to add `[trusted=yes]` so it looks like `deb [trusted=yes] http://apt.sturtz.cf/ ./` How do I make it so I do not need the `[trusted=yes]` by singing it?
Please note my website is not up so only I can download the apt package?